# Странный креш QT-приложения

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Пишу браузер с использованием QTWebEngine. Все нормально билдится, но при попытки запуска программа крешится. Вот код проекта в Qt Creator:

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow * mainWnd = new MainWindow();
    mainWnd -> show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <qtwebenginewidgetsglobal.h>
#include <QWebEngineView>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void createMenu();
    void createUrlBar();
    void createBrowserWindow();

    void loadHomepage();
    void loadUrl (QUrl);

    void applyLayouts();

    QMenuBar * menuBar;
    QMenu * menuFile, * menuFile2;

    QWidget * barWidget;
    QPushButton * barNextBut,* barBackBut, * barRefreshBut, * barEnterBut;
    QLineEdit * barUrlEdit;
    QComboBox * barSelectCB;

    QWebEngineView * browserWidget;

    QHBoxLayout * barLayout;
    QVBoxLayout * mainLayout;

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent)
{

    this -> setMinimumSize (1100, 600);

    createMenu();
    createUrlBar();
    createBrowserWindow();

    applyLayouts();

    loadHomepage();

}

void MainWindow::createMenu()
{

    menuBar = new QMenuBar();
    menuFile = new QMenu("File");
    menuFile2 = new QMenu("File2");
    menuFile -> addMenu (menuFile2);
    menuBar -> addMenu (menuFile);

}

void MainWindow::createUrlBar()
{

    //Контейнер;
    barWidget = new QWidget(this);
    barWidget -> setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
    barWidget -> setMaximumHeight(30);

    //Кнопки;
    barNextBut = new QPushButton(">");
    barBackBut = new QPushButton("<");
    barRefreshBut = new QPushButton("R");
    barEnterBut = new QPushButton("->");
    barNextBut -> setMaximumSize(21, 21);
    barBackBut -> setMaximumSize(21, 21);
    barRefreshBut -> setMaximumSize(21, 21);
    barEnterBut -> setMaximumSize(21, 21);

    barUrlEdit = new QLineEdit(barWidget); //Падает здесь;
    barUrlEdit -> setMinimumSize(256, 21);
    barUrlEdit -> setMaximumHeight(21);

    barSelectCB = new QComboBox(barWidget);
    barSelectCB -> setMinimumSize(256, 21);
    barSelectCB -> setMaximumSize(256, 21);

}

void MainWindow::createBrowserWindow()
{

    browserWidget = new QWebEngineView(this);

}

void MainWindow::loadHomepage()
{

    QUrl * url = new QUrl("http://google.ru");
    loadUrl(*url);
    delete(url);

}

void MainWindow::loadUrl (QUrl url)
{

    browserWidget -> load(url);

}

void MainWindow::applyLayouts ()
{

    barLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    barLayout -> setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    barLayout -> addWidget(barSelectCB);
    barLayout -> addWidget(barBackBut);
    barLayout -> addWidget(barNextBut);
    barLayout -> addWidget(barUrlEdit);
    barLayout -> addWidget(barRefreshBut);
    barLayout -> addWidget(barEnterBut);
    barWidget -> setLayout(barLayout);

    mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    mainLayout -> setDirection(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom);
    mainLayout -> setMenuBar(menuBar);
    mainLayout -> addWidget (barWidget);
    mainLayout -> addWidget (browserWidget);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

}
```

И project.pro файл:

```
QT += widgets
QT      +=  webenginewidgets

HEADERS =   mainwindow.h
SOURCES =   main.cpp \
mainwindow.cpp
```

Дебаггер показывает `:-1: warning: Exception at 0x7fefd4c9e5d, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance)"` в строке `barUrlEdit = new QLineEdit(barWidget)`. Самое интересное, что если не делать переменные свойствами класса, а объявлять их в конструкторе (то есть все операции производятся внутри конструктора, а не в методах), то все отлично работает. Прошу помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Разберитесь с тем фактом, что наследников Q_OBJECT надо привязывать к родительским элементам, чтобы они удалялись механизмами qt, а не вашим деструктором.